# Creating dynamic textview inside the listview in android

Tags: android, listview, textview, baseadapter

I am creating the programmatically `TextView` inside the `ListView` items, For it have done some following code.But not getting the desire solution, so please help me out from to solve my problem.

Here is my **class**.

```
package com.tv.ravindra;

/**
 * Created by Ravindra  on 22/01/16.
 */
public class DemoClass extends Activity {

    ListView list_demo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo);

        list_demo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_demo);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("One");
        arrayList.add("Two");
        arrayList.add("Three");
        arrayList.add("Four");

        DemoAdapter adapter = new DemoAdapter(DemoClass.this,arrayList);

        list_demo.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public class DemoAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        Activity activity;
        ArrayList<String> arrayList =  new ArrayList<String>();

        public DemoAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> arrayList)
        {

            this.activity = activity;
            this.arrayList = arrayList;

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        public class ViewHolder {

            TextView header_text_tv;
            RelativeLayout child_ll;

        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder _viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {


                _viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater _layInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = _layInflater.inflate(R.layout.demo_item, null);

                _viewHolder.header_text_tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_text_tv);
                _viewHolder.child_ll = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_ll);


                convertView.setTag(_viewHolder);


            } else {
                _viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            _viewHolder.header_text_tv.setText(arrayList.get(position));


            for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
            {
                TextView msg = new TextView(activity);
                msg.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_blue_color));
                msg.setText("Number "+i);
                msg.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                msg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                msg.setLayoutParams(params);

                _viewHolder.child_ll.addView(msg);
            }

            return convertView;
        }
      }
    }
```

From above code I am getting the following output as in Image
[MY OUTPUT FROM ABOVE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzfjx.png)

But I want to get the output like these type of output as in the image [MY DESIRE THESE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD1uH.png)

From my output from my above code , all the testview overlay on each other and only last item is visible that is **Number10** in my first image.

So friends please help me to short out from these problem.

Comment: Your output from above code and desigred output totally varies.. I cant co-relate both the screens!!

Comment: Means @Harry ... Actually i want to create the multiple textview inside the listview row....In my First image , i am not getting proper solution.....Second image shows that what i am want to implement

Answer (score 1):

hi try this way it may help you..

```
   RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int prevTextViewId = 0;     
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {                       
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Text "+i);     
        int curTextViewId = prevTextViewId + 1;
        textView.setId(curTextViewId);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, prevTextViewId);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        prevTextViewId = curTextViewId;
        layout.addView(textView, params);
    }
```

Comment: ..thanks for yours answer... i am checking it...if it workable for me than , i will happily mark answeer as a right..thanks for your effort

Comment: Your solution quite useful, but bro...As it gives me VERTICAL output...What i want that it should give me HORIZONTAL out put means one after another

Comment: just change relative layout rule to right it will work

Comment: Hello bro @MPG ...I am not getting the desire solution from your above code....look at these image which i am getting as output from your code http://postimg.org/image/pkykhnoyt/

Comment: As i have posted the second image in my question..please look at it

Comment: thanks @MPG ..for yours valueable effort.. +1 for it :)

Answer (score 0):

This example code may help you out

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    view = inflateIfRequired(view, position, parent);
    bind(getItem(position), view);

    return view;
}

private void bind(Eddystone eddystone, View view) {

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    String name = StringToHex.convertHexToString(eddystone.instance);

    holder.macTextView.setText("");
    holder.rssiTextView.setText("");
    holder.eddystoneNamespaceTextView.setText("");
    holder.eddystoneInstanceIdTextView.setText("");
}

private View inflateIfRequired(View view, int position, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        view.setTag(new ViewHolder(view));
    }

    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    final TextView macTextView;
    final TextView rssiTextView;
    final TextView namespace;
    final TextView instanceId;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        macTextView = (TextView) view.findViewWithTag("mac");
        rssiTextView = (TextView) view.findViewWithTag("rssi");
        namespace = (TextView) view.findViewWithTag("namespace");
        instanceId = (TextView) view.findViewWithTag("instance_id");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer...It does not seems that answer , which i am looking for...any way thanks for yours valuable effort..

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate() method:

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("One");
arrayList.add("Two");
arrayList.add("Three");
arrayList.add("Four");


ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(DemoClass.this,arrayList);

list_demo.setAdapter(adapter);
```

you can use custom adapter(**BaseAdapter**) to add **TextView** as per the data in **ListView**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    TextView contact_number;
    List<String> arrayList;

    DataAdapter(Context c, List<String> arrayList) {
        this.context = c;
    this.arrayList=arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);

        textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setText(arrayList.get(position));

        return row;

    }
}
```

You also create one layout file for generate custom **TextView** as **single_row.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```